# Renaming File Name in android sdcard donot work

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Hi I try to get selected Image and Rename it and set it to show in image View.
but the problem is when I rename it it say "File Not Exist" other wise if I don't rename the file it's work just fine.

this is the code in my Activity result for Get Image is sdcard:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        Log.e("URI Get Path", selectedImage.getPath());

        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };



        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

        Log.e("Picture Path 1 ", picturePath);

        String currentFileName = picturePath.substring(picturePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        Log.e("Current File Name",currentFileName);

        File sdcard = new File(picturePath.substring(0, picturePath.lastIndexOf("/")));
        File from = new File(sdcard,currentFileName);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        File to;

        if(currentFileName.contains("_"))
            to = new File(sdcard,User_Info.user_id + "___" + String.valueOf(c.getTimeInMillis()) + "__" +  currentFileName.substring(currentFileName.lastIndexOf("_") + 1) );
        else
            to = new File(sdcard,User_Info.user_id + "___" + String.valueOf(c.getTimeInMillis()) + "__" +  currentFileName);

        if(from.exists())
            from.renameTo(to);
        else
            Log.e("from not exist", from.getAbsolutePath());

        Log.e("From After Change", from.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.e("To After Change", to.getAbsolutePath());

        if(to.exists())
            picturePath = to.getAbsolutePath();
        else
            Log.e("to not exist", to.getAbsolutePath());

        cursor.close();

        Log.e("picturepath", picturePath);
```

and this is the Log:

```
07-04 23:11:11.730: E/URI Get Path(32250): /external/images/media/13031
07-04 23:11:11.770: E/Picture Path 1(32250): /mnt/sdcard/156___1435700963195__2006112342.jpg
07-04 23:11:11.780: E/Current File Name(32250): 156___1435700963195__2006112342.jpg
07-04 23:11:11.820: E/from not exist(32250): /mnt/sdcard/156___1435700963195__2006112342.jpg
07-04 23:11:11.820: E/From After Change(32250): /mnt/sdcard/156___1435700963195__2006112342.jpg
07-04 23:11:11.820: E/To After Change(32250): /mnt/sdcard/156___1436037071817__2006112342.jpg
07-04 23:11:11.830: E/to not exist(32250): /mnt/sdcard/156___1436037071817__2006112342.jpg
07-04 23:11:11.840: E/picturepath(32250): /mnt/sdcard/156___1435700963195__2006112342.jpg
07-04 23:11:11.860: E/BitmapFactory(32250): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/156___1435700963195__2006112342.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: OK I found something strange : "from is not exist" why and I see that the picture name that get from the activityrezult is wrong or I don't know how is this possible. Actually if I Choose to show images from something but not the gallery is send a true image name the problem is it's crash do to not using gallery any one can tell me what is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

you rename file and check source file again! you must check renamed file!
actually this line

```
if(from.exists())
```

always return false, because in previous line your renamed file.

```
from.renameTo(to);
```

Comment: I Make a change in my codes and add log can you see any thing else I just get confused.

Comment: what really want to do? why you want to rename file?

Comment: I have to send image to server , but the server wants me to send it a time in the way you see. so I have to rename the file to this way.